# What is the first use of "glamour" to describe magic?

Tags: history-of, mythology

There are a number of stories about magical beings, typically the Fae, that are said to possess "glamour" which gives them a variety of powers. Typically these abilities are somehow illusory but can nonetheless affect the world.

Was the term used in the original myths? If not, when was it first used?

Comment: Isn't this more an English Language and Usage SE question?

Comment: Eymology questions and language history questions are better asked on [ELU:SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/). Mythology questions are better asked on [Mythology and Folklore:SE](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Not really based on any hard evidence, what I have found indicates that it is an old word with somewhat murky etymology, and then it was revived as a term to mean enchantments by Sir Walter Scott in the late 1700's/early 1800's, so the modern usage can most likely be attributed to Sir Walter Scott. Specifically, *Lay of the Last Minstrel*, [Canto 3 Section IX](http://www.theotherpages.org/poems/canto03.html) (Published 1805).

> A moment then the volume spread,
> And one short spell therein he read:
> It had much of glamour might;
> Could make a ladye seem a knight;

Here is the [entry on it from etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/glamour)

> glamour (n.)
>
> 1720, Scottish, "magic, enchantment" (especially in phrase to cast the glamor), a variant of Scottish gramarye "magic, enchantment, spell," said to be an alteration of English grammar (q.v.) in a specialized use of that word's medieval sense of "any sort of scholarship, especially occult learning," the latter sense attested from c. 1500 in English but said to have been more common in Medieval Latin. Popularized in English by the writings of Sir Walter Scott (1771-1832). Sense of "magical beauty, alluring charm" first recorded 1840. As that quality of attractiveness especially associated with Hollywood, high-fashion, celebrity, etc., by 1939.
>
> Jamieson's 1825 supplement to his "Etymological Dictionary of the Scottish Language" has glamour-gift "the power of enchantment; metaph. applied to female fascination." Jamieson's original edition (1808) looked to Old Norse for the source of the word. Zoëga's Old Icelandic dictionary has glám-sýni "illusion," probably from the same root as gleam.

There is a slightly fanciful interpretation that comes from Charles Mackay's "[Dictionary of Lowland Scotch](https://books.google.com/books?id=zLACAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA70&dq=%22glamour%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCpO7j0-LaAhVCMd8KHY5PCtsQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22glamour%22&f=false)" that it comes from the Scottish "glaodh mor" or a great shout, but his attempt was not really serious etymology, but rather to show that all words derive from Scots Gaelic.

The book "[Word Origins..and How We Know Them: Etymology for Everyone](https://books.google.com/books?id=sMiRc-JFIfMC&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=gramarye%20origins&source=bl&ots=XNc4yEgVGK&sig=pGqKxzS4xFmEAovTalwx5wg_HZ0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ39zq1eLaAhWMjlkKHSMmDZE4ChDoATAJegQIABBI#v=onepage&q=gramarye%20origins&f=false)" attributes it back through the alternative meanings of [grammar, or gramaire](https://books.google.com/books?id=sMiRc-JFIfMC&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=gramarye%20origins&source=bl&ots=XNc4yEgVGK&sig=pGqKxzS4xFmEAovTalwx5wg_HZ0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ39zq1eLaAhWMjlkKHSMmDZE4ChDoATAJegQIABBI#v=onepage&q=gramarye%20origins&f=false), as follows:

> Old French had *gramaire* (grammar) (a formation without direct antecedents in Greek or Latin), and in the thirteenth century, its evil twin *grimoir* was born. Initially, it referred to Lain grammer only (an allusion to French *grimaud [morose, sullen]?) as something unintelligible, and soon came to mean "a book of occult learning".

Followed with

> *grimoire* reached England around the fourteenth century and had the form *gramarie*. Walter Scott revived its medieval sense "magic", and this is the reason *gramary* and *gramarye* still turn up in our thickest dictionaries. But then, in the north, alterations of *gramarie* appeared. The recorded forms are numerous, *glamer, glamor, glamour, glamerie, glammerie*, and *glaumerie*. It was again Walter Scott who revived *glamor*...